# How to convert NSDecimalNumber to byte array if NSDecimalNumber is bigger than Uint64?

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdecimalnumber

I want to convert an NSDecimalNumber to a byte array. Also, I do not want to use any library for that like BigInt, BInt, etc.

I tried this one:

```
static func toByteArray<T>(_ value: T) -> [UInt8] {
    var value = value
    return withUnsafeBytes(of: &value) { Array($0) }
}
let value =  NSDecimalNumber(string: "...")
let bytes = toByteArray(value.uint64Value)
```

If the number is not bigger than Uint64, it works great. But, what if it is, how can we convert it?

Comment: What is the question, "How to convert NSDecimalNumber to byte array?" or "what happens if the number is bigger than Uint64?"?

Comment: How to convert NSDecimalNumber to byte array if NSDecimalNumber is bigger than Uint64? I 've just changed the question. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: Can you give an example of a `value` and the expexted `bytes`? Is `value` always a whole number?

Comment: for example if the value is "59785897542892656787456", the value has to be [12, 169, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0 ,0]. Like new BigInteger("59785897542892656787456").toByteArray in java.

Comment: Take a look at `value.decimalValue` and its `_mantissa`.

Comment: @Rob `_mantissa` of `NSDecimal` is 128 binary positions.

Comment: Good point. I was thrown off by by the `NSDecimalNumber.init(mantissa:exponent:isNegative:)`, whose `mantissa` is `UInt64`. But the mantissa is, actually 128 bits, capable of handling decimal integer up to 38 digits long. But my point, that it can't handle arbitrary length integers, whereas other representations can, still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is obviously the use of `uint64Value`, which obviously cannot represent any value greater than `UInt64.max`, and your example, 59,785,897,542,892,656,787,456, is larger than that.

If you want to grab the byte representations of the 128 bit mantissa, you can use `_mantissa` tuple of `UInt16` words of `Decimal`, and convert them to bytes if you want. E.g.

```
extension Decimal {
    var byteArray: [UInt8] {
        return [_mantissa.0,
                _mantissa.1,
                _mantissa.2,
                _mantissa.3,
                _mantissa.4,
                _mantissa.5,
                _mantissa.6,
                _mantissa.7]
            .flatMap { [UInt8($0 & 0xff), UInt8($0 >> 8)] }
    }
}
```

And

```
if let foo = Decimal(string: "59785897542892656787456") {
    print(foo.byteArray)
}
```

Returning:

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 169, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

This, admittedly, only defers the problem, breaking the 64-bit limit of your `uint64Value` approach, but is still constrained to the inherent 128-bit limit of `NSDecimalNumber`/`Decimal`. To capture numbers greater than 128 bits, you'd need a completely different representation.

---

NB: This also assumes that the exponent is `0`. If, however, you had some large number, e.g. 4.2e101 (4.2 * 10<sup>101</sup>), the exponent will be `100` and the mantissa will simply be `42`, which I bet is probably not what you want in your byte array. Then again, this is an example of a number that is too large to represent as a single 128 bit integer, anyway:

```
if let foo = Decimal(string: "4.2e101") {
    print(foo.byteArray)
    print(foo.exponent)
}
```

Yielding:

> [42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>   100

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `value.uint64Value` and not `value`. So the number will be *wrapped around* zero to fit the NSDecimal into a UInt64 format.

Passing `"18446744073709551616"` (which is the string corresponding to `UInt64.max` + 1) is equivalent to passing `"0"`. Passing `"18446744073709551617"` (which is the string corresponding to `UInt64.max` + 2) is equivalent to passing `"1"`.

Comment: passing NSDecimalNumber does not give the correct result.

Comment: This answers your original question explaining what happens when the number is bigger than UInt64.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: Is `MemoryLayout<NSDecimalNumber>.size` the size of a pointer? The size of a `NSDecimalNumber` object is irrelevant. It is an object-oriented  wrapper around `NSDecimal` (`Decimal` in Swift). `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSDecimal` can handle strings `"18446744073709551616"` and `"18446744073709551617"`. Method `uint64Value` can't convert these values to `UInt64`.